# Nested Condition Statements to its equivalent TreeStucture

Tags: c#, tree

I have a string containing a C function with condition statements inside.

```
string inputFunction = "if(x > 10)
{
    if(x == 11)
    {
        //more conditions
    }
    if(x == 12)
    {
    }
}";
```

using regular expression I parse for condition statements then, parse for its code block. then repeat the process again for the next conditions. Then I plan to store them in a class I've created:

```
class Condition
{
     public string ConditionString { get; set; }
     public string ParentCondition { get; set; }
     public string ChildConditions { get; set; }
}
```

Now the problem is: I cannot create a parent-child relationship with my current algorithm.

I am only able to identify the first set of parents. I can repeat the process again to parse for their children, but those children can also have child conditions inside. Does anyone have a suggestion or s there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

For tree structure, the golden rule is to have collection of entity within itself.

I think your class structure should be this

```
class Condition
{
    public string ConditionString{get;set;}
    public Condition ParentCondition{get;set;}
    public List<Condition> ChildConditions{get;set;} // in case there are more 
                                                     // than one conditions.
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, do you have a suggestion on how i can populate the list of ChildConditions?